# What gems are in the default gemset for Ruby 2.0.0-p247?

Tags: ruby, gemset

By accident I ran `rvm gemset empty default`.

Can someone list all gems from gemset `default` for `ruby-2.0.0-p247` so I can reinstall them manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, it's still possible to restore all your gems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CURRENT_GEMSET=$( rvm current )
CACHE_FOLDER=~/.rvm/gems/$CURRENT_GEMSET/cache
CACHED_GEMS=$CACHE_FOLDER/*.gem

for gem_file in $CACHED_GEMS
do
  GEM_FILES=$GEM_FILES' '$gem_file
done

gem install $GEM_FILES
```

You may take a look at `~/.rvm/gems/$( rvm current )/cache` folder first. All `gem`s should be there.

*Edit:*

```
rvm gemset empty
```

Removes all the **installed** gems for gemset. But gems are still in `~/.rvm/gems/$( rvm current )/cache` folder(e.g. `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/cache`, `~/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@my_gemset/cache`) and you are still able to install them.

A bit of explanations regarding script:

1. `rvm current` Print the current Ruby version and the name of any gemset being used(from `rvm usage current`). You may invoke `rvm gemset use` first in order to choose gemset you want to restore.
2. `~/.rvm/gems/$( rvm current )/cache` is a cache folder for current gemset and is the same as `$GEM_HOME/cache`.
3. `~/.rvm/gems/$( rvm current )/cache/*.gem` is a regexp for gems in cache folder.
4. Loop through the file names and concatenate them into a single string

   ```
   for gem_file in $CACHED_GEMS
   do
     GEM_FILES=$gem_file' '$GEM_FILES
   done
   ```
5. `gem install $GEM_FILES` reinstalls you gems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
alexandr@alexandr-2pcdesktop:~/RailsWork/Achivity$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-01-07 trunk 38733) [i686-linux]
alexandr@alexandr-2pcdesktop:~/RailsWork/Achivity$ rvm @global do gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
rake (10.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
```

=====Updated======

```
alexandr@alexandr-2pcdesktop:~/RailsWork/Achivity$ rvm default do gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
actionpack (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
actionpack-action_caching (1.0.0)
actionpack-page_caching (1.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
capybara (2.1.0)
childprocess (0.3.9)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3, 1.6.2)
commonjs (0.2.6)
database_cleaner (1.0.1)
devise (3.0.0.rc, 2.2.4, 1.5.4)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
ffi (1.9.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
jar_wrapper (0.1.7)
jbuilder (1.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.2, 3.0.1)
json (1.8.0)
less (2.3.2)
less-rails (2.3.3)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86-linux)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.7)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0, 0.0.7)
paperclip (3.4.2)
pg (0.15.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
protected_attributes (1.0.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0)
rails-observers (0.1.1)
railties (4.0.0, 3.2.13)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (3.12.2)
ref (1.0.5)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.0)
sdoc (0.3.20)
selenium (0.2.10)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
shoulda-matchers (2.2.0)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.2.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.7)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
warden (1.2.1)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0)
zip (2.0.2)
```

But all of them are from Gemfile.

Comment: It's from `global`. I remember that in `default` there were `json` and `bigdecimal` gems, maybe some more, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AlexFedoseev as I can see, there are you own installed gems, that you installed with bundler. (In example, created Rails app and ran bundle install). But if you want, I can show you mine in updated version of post.

Comment: @AlexFedoseev you can see it above. But I'm sure, that they are from my Gemfile. So you can do bundle install in your project and I think, that it will install all important gems.

Comment: I found [this link](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html), the list of additional system gems in the middle of the page.